# Параллельный поиск подстроки в строке

Tags: c, многопоточность, распараллеливание

Задача: Распараллелить поиск подстроки в строке.

Если использовать тривиальный алгоритм (прикладывать образец во все места строки), то распараллелить можно, распределив интервалы по потокам (например, 1 поток - прикладывать к 1..4 позиции, 2 поток - 5..8 позиции и т.д.). Какие еще алгоритмы поиска подстроки также можно распараллелить?(использовать тривиальный способ не хочется)

Средства разработки: С, POSIX Threads.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
char *pattern;
struct args
{
    int num_thread;
    char *pattern;
    char *line;
    long int x0;
    long int x1;
};
char* read_pattern(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    long int lSize;
    char *buffer;
    fp = fopen ( filename , "rb" );
    if( !fp ) perror(filename),exit(1);
    fseek( fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    lSize = ftell( fp );
    rewind( fp );
    printf("Size = %ld\n",lSize);
    /* allocate memory for entire content */
    buffer = calloc( 1, lSize+1 );
    if( !buffer ) fclose(fp),fputs("memory alloc fails",stderr),exit(1);

    /* copy the file into the buffer */
    if( 1!=fread( buffer , lSize, 1 , fp) )   
    fclose(fp),free(buffer),fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);
    fclose(fp);
    return buffer;
}
void* seek_substring_KMP (void *ptr)
{
    struct args * a = (struct args*)ptr;
    long int i, j, N, M;
    N = a->x1-a->x0;
    M = strlen(a->line);
    int *d =(int*)malloc(M*sizeof(int)); /* динамический массив длины М*/

    /* Вычисление префикс-функции */
    d[0]=0;
    for(i=1,j=0;i<M;i++)
    {
            while(j>0 && a->line[j]!=a->line[i])
                    j = d[j-1];
            if(a->line[j]==a->line[i])
                    j++;
            d[i]=j;
    }
    /* поиск */
    for(i=a->x0,j=0;i<a->x1; i++)
    {
            while(j>0 && a->line[j]!=a->pattern[i])
                    j=d[j-1];
            if(a->line[j]==a->pattern[i])
                    j++;
            if (j==M)
            {
                   printf("Pos = %ld\n",i-j+1);
            }
    }
    free (d); /* освобождение памяти массива d */
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    }
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
    if(argc!=4) return 0;
    pattern = read_pattern(argv[1]);
    char *line = read_pattern(argv[2]);
    int threads_count = atoi(argv[3]);
    printf("Threads count = %d\n",threads_count);
    int NUM =1+(strlen(pattern)/(threads_count));
    struct args * a = (struct args*)malloc(threads_count*sizeof(struct args));
    pthread_t *threads = (pthread_t*)malloc(threads_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
    int error_code;
    for(int i=0;i<threads_count;i++)
    {
            a[i].num_thread = i;
            a[i].pattern = pattern;
            a[i].line = line;
            a[i].x0=i*NUM;

            if(i==threads_count-1)
            {
                    a[i].x1 = strlen(pattern) - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                    a[i].x1 = i*NUM + strlen(line) + NUM -1;
            }
    }
    clock_t t = clock();
    for(int i=0;i<threads_count;i++)
    {
            error_code = pthread_create( &threads[i], NULL, seek_substring_KMP, (void*) &a[i]);
            if(error_code)
            {
                    fprintf(stderr,"Error - pthread_create() return code: %d\n",error_code);
                    exit(0);
            }
            //else printf("Thread %d is created\n",i);

    }
    for(int i = 0; i<threads_count;i++)
    {
            pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
    }
    t = clock() - t;
    free(a);
    free(threads);
    printf("Work time = %f\n",((float)t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: интервалы должны перекрываться на длину искомой подстроки

Comment: @PashaPash для чего? Тут ведь в отрезке просто указываются начальная и конечная позиции в строке, начиная с которых прикладывается подстрока.

Comment: @Regent ок, значит я просто не так понял слово "позиция". но вообще вроде почти любой алгоритм поиска подстроки хорошо распараллеливается, если просто разбить входную строку на перекрывающиеся интервалы, и тупо запустить поиск в каждом.

Comment: естественно, интервалы задаются с учетом длины строки-образца

Answer (score 3):

1. Взять любой готовый метод поиска подстроки в строке (не обязательно прикладывание, что-то из нормальных способов, которые работают за почти линейное время. ну или хотя бы `strstr`)
2. Разбить входную строку на перекрывающиеся интервалы - с перекрытием размером в искомую подстроку минус один.
3. Запустить поиск в каждом интервале в отдельном потоке.

Т.е. для строки длиной в 10000 и подстроки длиной в 5 взять интервалы 0-1003, 1000-2003 и т.д. Запустить поиск в каждом из них.

Comment: Не знаю насчет всех алгоритмов, но известные мне алгоритмы Бойера-Мура и Ахо-Корасик вполне должны так распараллелиться. Вроде они не "тривиальные".

Comment: @Regent я и не говорил что нужно брать тривиальный алгоритм. даже наоборот - можно взять любой нормальный **готовый** способ.

Comment: Интересно, начиная с какого размера строки скорость параллельного поиска превысит скорость последовательного.

Comment: @PashaPash а я не говорил, что вы говорили про тривиальный :) Это я к тому написал, что автор хотел нетривиальный, и озвученные "вроде нетривиальные" вполне себе должны работать. Собственно, я вполне согласен с ответом.

Comment: @avp есть подозрение что не превысит вообще. нормальный процессор будет перебирать символы гораздо быстрее, чем их способна отдать память. а память на все процессоры одна.

Comment: Ну, Вы просто стоимость синхронизации (с очередью запросов для пула потоков) или create/join (для запуска каждый раз) забыли учесть.

Comment: @avp я это и имел ввиду - скорее однопоточный вариант всегда будет быстрее

Comment: Ага. Правда, для многомегабайтных строк  я бы поставил на многопоточный вариант.

Comment: @avp, посчитал на 8 потоках со строкой 41Мб, однопоточный вариант оказался быстрее, примерно 0.24c против 0.28.

Comment: @avp код указал в вопросе

Comment: @Shach не сказал бы что это суперрезультат - у меня 5-ти строчный код на C# с тупо `while (String.IndexOf > -1)` перебирает 200+Mb за 110 ms. Могу добавить в вопрос, или выложить куда-нибудь (не уверен, взлетит ли он под моно)

Comment: @PashaPash суть в том, что ускорения путем распараллеливания не удалось добиться.

Comment: @Shach вполне ожидаемый результат :)

Comment: @PashaPash, согласен, но по заданию требуется добиться ускорения. Есть подозрение, что параллельный код не оптимизирован.
P.S. Выкладывайте:)

Comment: @PashaPash функция определения времени криво работала, все таки есть ускорение)

Comment: @Shach вы еще уберите вывод на консоль из поиска. он очень тормозит, если результатов много.

Comment: Shach, а если попробовать не на 8 потоках, а только на 2ух ?